Finding GeoJSON layer on Maputnik
I am using the maputnik editor and I have added a small geojson polygon. Now I want to see geojson and edit its styles.
How do I achieve this?
I am not able to find my geojson in the big map. Although I did add the Open layers underneath and was able to find it eventually but I want to be able to click on layer and zoom into it.
